# System.Web.Mvc not functioning as expected after Windows Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces, windows-update

After yesterday's Windows Update, I seem to have issues building my projects.

```
Related Windows Updates could be:
ASP.NET MVC 2.0: KB2993939
ASP.NET MVC 3.0: KB2993937
ASP.NET MVC 4.0: KB2993928
ASP.NET MVC 5.0: KB2992080
ASP.NET MVC 5.1: KB2994397
```

[image: System.Web.Mvc-related errors]

These errors all seem to be related to the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace of which I checked; it is still being associated with the project under `References`. What could have gone wrong with my MVC project during the Windows Update, and how should I go about rectifying it?

Here is the log that indicates the updates administered today:

[image: 16/10/2014's Windows Update]

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406804/after-windows-update-the-type-or-namespace-name-html-does-not-exist-in-the-na?noredirect=1#comment41463426_26406804

Comment: Solved in the related question ^^

Comment: Microsoft's statement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The recent updates have incremented version numbers

3.0.0.0 -> 3.0.0.1 and 4.0.0.0 -> 4.0.0.1

I had to remove the reference and re-add (System.Web.Mvc is found in Assemblies >Extensions are of the Add Reference dialogue)

Comment: This works but I have quite a number of projects in my solution, and I don't want to re-reference the assemblies on each and every one of them...

Comment: @matt you could do a find and replace on the project files replacing `System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,` with `System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1,`

Comment: This solved only part of my windows "update problems". Furthermore I had to change connection string to named instance. I have two SQL server instances (2008 and 2012) and after windows update in October 2014 localhost started to point to the second instance of sql server.

Answer (score 10):

I have same problem today after windows update.
There is my solution.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.0.0 -Project PROJECTNAME
```

Also you can try use these code maybe it helps.

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Force
```

Goodluck.

Comment: Microsoft made a statement of this issue. They says like me.
[There is link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx)
@matt

Comment: -1: 1. MVC 5.2.x was not affected by [MS14-059](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms14-059.aspx); 2. 5.2 has been replaced by 5.2.2 (well before MS14-059).

Comment: My projects mvc 5.2.0.0 after windows update all updated 5.2.2.0 .

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` worked for me. The whole solution is now on `v5.2.2.0`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to fix this:

**Option 1: Add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc using NuGet**

Use NuGet to add the latest revision of the MVC version you depend on to your project. Microsft recommends this approach.

**Option 2: Update assembly reference**

If you add a new assymbly reference to your project you'll see that the System.Web.Mvc assemblies are now versioned x.0.0.1.

---

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

I would suggest against bluntly attempting reinstalling MVC. Allthough it worked for me in the end, you'll run into trouble with NuGet being bundled with the MVC installer.

You need to uninstall NuGet prior to reinstalling MVC because NuGet still being present causes the MVC installer to refuse to install or to fail.

In addition I don't see why reinstalling MVC will prevent Windows Update from applying the update again after you reinstalled MVC.

Answer (score 1):

As the patch has incremented the version number has risen from (for MVC4 it has risen from 4.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1) the Reference Path in the project files needs to change from:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

to

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Obviously adjust the hint path as appropriate, and make similar changes for other versions of MVC

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem.

Microsoft changed the Version from 3.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.1

I guess this is the reason Visual Studio can't find the reference, because the regular setting is "Use specific version - true".

In my case i can't change the setting to false, because I am using Mvc4 on the same machine and it would automatically use the version 4 dll.

A solution is to remove the project reference of System.Web.Mvc.dll and add it again. Then VS will use the Version-3.0.0.1-DLL as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the MVC assembly

download link : http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 0):

I tried [mh28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551455/mh28)'s solution, which proposed the following:

> The recent updates have incremented version numbers
>
> 3.0.0.0 -> 3.0.0.1 and 4.0.0.0 -> 4.0.0.1
>
> I had to remove the reference and re-add (System.Web.Mvc is found in
>   Assemblies >Extensions are of the Add Reference dialogue)

On top of that, it was also suggested that I run a **Find and Replace** throughout my scope of interest; I tried that, but failed. Seems like **Find and Replace** doesn't apply to .csproj files.

What I did next was to find a text replacing tool (see [Ecobyte Replace Text](http://www.ecobyte.com/replacetext/)) and run the program using the following settings:

[image: Ecobyte Replace Text settings]

All my projects built as per normal thereafter, and I'm not seeing any side effects (despite not making any changes in the `web.config` files). I'm not sure (and I don't think) this is the best solution, and I don't think this is a silver bullet for all `System.Web.Mvc` issues affected by the security-related Windows Update for .NET, but I think it'd be useful for specific cases whereby there're a whole lot of projects to re-reference.

Comment: No need for third party tools, CTRL+Shift+F (Find in Files) and CTRL+Shift+H (Replace in Files) in Visual Studio are your friends ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install/repair ASP.NET MVC using the last versions of **MSI packages** available from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44533).

If you use `bindingRedirect` in `web.config` it could be required (it was not needed in my projects) to update the sections too. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425366/315935). It all still not helps I would recommend to examine *other* web.config files in your project, like `~/Views/web.config` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue recently.

After Windows Update - my project in Visual Studio suddenly had 500+ errors - all related to system.web.mvc

So I deleted the reference and re-added it - found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies

Great - project compiles.

Put it on site - get "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"

After much messing around, I went to site, downloaded the version of it off there - referenced it - it worked on my laptop AND on site

phew!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was present for me. However, the fix was much more simplified than using nuget to fix or making updates to web.config. 
My issue was resolved by manually updating the text in {ProjectName}.csproj from

Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=**3.0.0.1**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"

to

Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=**3.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
, and checking in the changes, and running a build in the build agent machine, which, for me, was TeamCity.

Even though this caused build errors locally, it resolved the source control/Team City build errors.

I realize that this doesnt allow me to build locally, without having making changes to the csproj file. However, after I checkin the change as I did above(changing it from 3.0.0.1 to 3.0.0.0), I can update the project locally to use the new version (3.0.0.1), and just not check in the changes to csproj. 
I imagine someone may have a similar scenario.