# After Windows update "The type or namespace name 'Html' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc'"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-update

I did a Windows update and afterwards my asp.net mvc 5 application will no longer load complaining about

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Html' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc'
```

indicating my views web.config is at fault

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Ogre.Extensions" />
        <add namespace="Newtonsoft.Json"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Now this is very confusing. In my project itself I can see the `Html` namespace, opening my assembly in ILSpy I can navigate to the bound `System.Web.Mvc` and I can it as well, and the fusion log is not showing any suspicious binding errors.

It's as if *just* my views are getting bound (successfully) to an old version of Mvc. Why would that ever happen? How can I fix it?

Let me be clear that there have been no configuration or even code changes. This is all on my dev machine on IISExpress. It was running, I did the update and rebooted and now it is no longer running.

Here are my recent installs from the update. I could start removing them one by one, but I want to know what is actually going wrong as it feels like I'm missing part of the story.

[image: Installs from the update]

Comment: Are your project references OK?

Comment: @DavidG yes, the project builds just fine and there are no broken references

Comment: Your app pool in IIS isn't set to use .Net Framework 2 by any chance?

Comment: @DavidG this is in IISExpress all running locally. Like I said, there have been no configuration changes between it running and not running.

Comment: I'm having same problem with IISExpress, looking forward for the answer

Comment: Does updating your `<host>` factoryType to 5.1.0.0 change anything?

Comment: @BradChristie no, and technically we're still using `5.0.0` so I would be surprised if it did. `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_5.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll` definitely exists (as does the `5.0.1` version)

Comment: This SO is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396489/system-web-mvc-not-functioning-as-expected-after-windows-update

Comment: Seems we may have an epidemic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407533/windows-update-october-15-broke-mvc-site

Comment: @kingdango might be related, but the top answer on there rewires `System.Web.Mvc` to 4.0.0.1 in the GAC rather than 5.0.0 in my nuget packages. I do not want that!

Comment: Yea, me either :)  Hoping to find a resolution on this ASAP, thanks for the update w/o guidance MS! :/

Comment: We've noticed that our System.Web.Mvc project reference now has Copy Local set to False instead of True. Setting Copy Local back to True fixes the issue but doesn't explain why it was changed after the patch. We have several machines with the security update and several without. In every case those with the update open the solution (in multiple branches of source control) and Copy Local is False. For those with unpatched machines Copy Local is set to True like it is in source control.

Comment: For me, Visual Studio said Copy Local was `true`, but it wasn't actually copying the file to the bin folder.  I had to manually edit `<Private>True</Private>` into my project file.

Comment: Glad it's not just me. Getting the projects building was easy enough, fixing the broken site was irritating until I noticed that the Copy Local was set to false. Particularly great that it all worked fine on the test server, which must have updated the GAC itself I assume, so only the live one broke. Cheers MS. Although on the whole I'd prefer to have security fixes I guess.

Comment: Try to install/repair the last versions of **MSI packages of ASP.NET MVC** from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44533)

Comment: Related: [`System.Web.MVC` not copied to `bin` folder since MS14-059](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26467078/25124)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Holy crap, thanks to @Nevada-Williford for the hint. Going in and setting my `System.Web.Mvc` reference to `<Private>True</Private>` (Copy Local = True) fixed it. Note, that before the update everything was working, after the update I had to modify my csproj to get it working again.

**Working theory on what's going on:**

`Copy Local = True` and `<Private>True</Private>` used to be almost, [but not exactly, the same thing.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/11/18/the-copy-local-bug-in-visual-studio.aspx) The former was a Visual Studio setting, the latter an msbuild setting. If the msbuild setting was absent, the Visual Studio setting would be applied (as long as you were in VS). In this update I think they changed it so `Copy Local` just reflects the presence attribute.

In our project we do not have that attribute set explicitly but `Copy Local = True` so prior to the update `System.Web.Mvc.dll` gets copied to the bin directory. After the update, since the attribute is missing `Copy Local` shows `False` and you  have to set it to `True` to make sure you get a local copy.

Manually setting `Copy Local = True` (or adding that xml element to msbuild) fixes the issue.

**Edit:** While this appears to be the answer to the specific question, anyone coming here should read the comment thread and other answers - especially dmatson's - for more context, caveats, and related bugs.

Comment: Kind of makes sense. Looks like a (forced) migration and part of the vNext project where solutions rely on fewer dependencies coming from the framework.

Comment: Oh totally makes sense and a change for the better, but an unheralded out-of-band update that requires changes to existing code? Really bad form.

Comment: It's worth noting that this also breaks existing projects that have Copy Local = True already set. At least for me, the project was no longer copying the assembly locally. Toggling to Copy Local = false, saving, then back to true and saving fixed it.

Comment: [This seems like some sort of confirmation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx)

Comment: This can easily break your builds on your CI servers, confused the crap out of me the other day when my servers updated and were throwing this error but locally it was working (hadnt received the updates locally yet)

Comment: If anyone is confused in the future; it should be `System.Web.Mvc`, not `System.Mvc.Web`

Comment: Setting `CopyLocal=true` did not help us; see: [`System.Web.MVC` not copied to `bin` folder since MS14-059](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26467078/25124)

Answer (score 32):

This was broken for any users without `CopyLocal=true` (or, in MSBuild speak, `<Private>True</Private>`) by [MS14-059](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-059). MVC templates do set `<Private>True</Private>` by default, but if you use NuGet to update the MVC version, you lose that setting (see [NuGet bug #4344](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4344)).

There are two aspects to the problem:

1. Razor doesn't include a reference to MVC by default, so its compilation won't work unless some version of the MVC DLL exists in your bin folder.
2. If you deploy to a separate machine that doesn't have this update installed, the MVC DLL isn't included in your output anymore, so MVC will be missing.

You're seeing problem #1. To resolve both problems, I'd recommend making both of the following changes:

1. Add the following configuration to Views\Web.config:

   ```
   <system.web>
     <compilation>
       <assemblies>
         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
       </assemblies>
     </compilation>
   </system.web>
   ```
2. Set `CopyLocal=true` in the VS UI for the project reference, or manually add the following line below in the `Reference` in your .csproj file:

   ```
   <Private>True</Private>
   ```

So your full reference should look something like the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Note that NuGet will remove the CopyLocal/Private setting if you update packages again in the future. (For example, if you update to MVC 5.2 today). If that version of MVC is ever GAC'd, problem #1 above will not recur as long as you've added the configuration in step A above, but problem #2 could still happen again. To ensure this doesn't happen in the future, I'd recommend manually setting CopyLocal back to true any time you do a NuGet package update.

Comment: Holy cow that's awful. Everyone please go upvote that nuget bug.

Comment: Setting `CopyLocal=true` did not help us; see: [`System.Web.MVC` not copied to `bin` folder since MS14-059](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26467078/25124)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny is the reference in the project file marked as `<private>true</private>` though?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer See my updates on that post; it is missing private=true, however upgrading to MVC 5.2.2 fixed it, and did not introduce any changes there :-/

Answer (score 9):

1. You can go to References of current Project.
2. Right click in dll `System.Web.Mvc` and choose Properties
3. A Properties window will open
4. Change **Copy Local** to `True`

Comment: Thanks it works but how it solved just don't get idea! Can you please give some little bit description how it solved?

Answer (score 5):

Setting CopyLocal=true did not help. Cleaning the solution then closing it and reopening it again worked. You might need to close the entire Visual Studio instance as well.

Comment: What did that actually do to the csproj file? `CopyLocal=true` should just be a ui for making a change to the csproj file now.

Comment: Not sure what it did to the csproj file. Also CopyLocal was already set to true like other devs reported. However, all I know is after closing the solution or the Visual Studio instance and reopening it again, the error disappeared.

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding the Solution worked for me.  Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

This appears to have been caused by a Windows Update ([KB2990942](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=44533)) to fix security vulnerablity [MS14-059](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-059), allowing security feature bypass. Our builds stopped working on our build server after the Windows Update was installed, and updating the csproj files to use 4.0.0.1 for the System.Web.Mvc reference fixed the issue.

Microsoft's description of the vulnerability is:

> The vulnerability could allow security feature bypass if an attacker convinces a user to click a specially crafted link or to visit a webpage that contains specially crafted content designed to exploit the vulnerability. In a web-based attack scenario, an attacker could host a specially crafted website that is designed to exploit the vulnerability through a web browser, and then convince a user to view the website. The attacker could also take advantage of compromised websites and websites that accept or host user-provided content or advertisements. These websites could contain specially crafted content that could exploit the vulnerability. In all cases, however, an attacker would have no way to force users to view the attacker-controlled content. Instead, an attacker would have to convince users to take action, typically by getting them to click a link in an email message or in an Instant Messenger message that takes them to the attacker's website, or by getting them to open an attachment sent through email.

Comment: Soooo....that just basically says "it's a vulnerability where a user can be attacked via a webpage", right? Pretty useless description.

Answer (score 3):

As well as setting CopyLocal=true in the project reference you may also need to change the Web.Config file like so...

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Notice the newVersion="4.0.0.1". This worked for me, and I hope it helps a few people out as well.

Saves updating the MVC framework on any test/production servers.

Cheers Microsoft. You're the best!

Your attempt to make me look incompetent in front of my clients has been foiled yet again!

Comment: This will only work if you *have* that version of mvc available locally or in the gac

Comment: CopyLocal=True will put a local copy in the bin folder and run from that. Just make sure you upload it to the bin folder of the application on the test/production server.

Comment: Let me correct you there, `<private>true</private>` in your project file will be force it to be copied. `Copy Local = True` will *sometimes* force it to be copied because that entire feature is buggy. Unfortunately, as other people mentioned, an unrelated nuget bug will remove the `<private>True</private>` setting if you update from nuget and you will have to manually re-add it.

Comment: I personally don't use nuget to reference the system namespace as this seems a bit convoluted, as you have just pointed out with the 'buggyness' you mentioned. but each to their own hey! This has worked for me and hopefully will shed some light on it for some other people.

Answer (score 1):

As well as setting `CopyLocal=true` in the project reference you may also need to change the **Web.Config** file like so...

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I added `culture="neutral"` also, and all this solved the problem.