# System.Web.Razor.dll not copied to bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Problem**

We have an ASP.Net 5.2.3 project that we are attempting to upgrade to .NET 4.6.

When running it, we get the error message

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Note that we installed Microsoft.AspNet.Razor version 3.2.3 from NuGet, though the error message refers to version 3.0.0.0.

**Hack**

Now if I manually copy

> packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll

to

> TheWebProject\bin

the project runs just fine.

**GAC**

Note that there are two entries in

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Razor
>
> v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
>
> v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35

I'm aware that DLLs that are [present in the GAC ignore CopyLocal=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467078/system-web-mvc-not-copied-into-bin-folder-since-ms14-059-how-to-protect-against).  However, I don't understand why the project is both unable to resolve the reference from the GAC, and unwilling to copy the version referenced using NuGet to the bin folder.

**web.config**

We have the following binding redirects in web.config that were presumably placed there by the NuGet installer

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

We also tried setting newVersion="3.2.3.0" to match the version as it appears in the NuGet package manager.  When we change both of those to

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.3.0" newVersion="3.2.3.0" />
```

we get a slightly different error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**Question**

How should the project references be setup to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have a reference to the 3.0.0.0 assembly in your web.config?

Comment: @mjw: Yes, updated the question with the specifics.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add assembly redirects to your *.config file. Open up the Package Manager Console and enter this command: `Add-BindingRedirect [-ProjectName]`

reference: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Nov/29/Updating-Assembly-Redirects-with-NuGet and https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference

Comment: That's a cool command, I did not know about it.  However, after running it, it made the same change to the binding redirect that we tried by hand (updated it to 3.2.3).

Comment: Could there be a *seperate* dependent assembly that has been compiled against an older version of System.Web.Razor?

Comment: Exactly what one of the team members said when we first started digging into this :-)

Comment: `Could there be a seperate dependent assembly` we checked for that pretty carefully, but good thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the reference in the reference list and set "Copy Local" to "True".

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, your config is forcing it to 3.0.0.0. Try this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: We already tried that.  I updated the question to make that clearer, and showed the error we got.