# MVC Upgrade 4.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1 - breaks libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For reference please see:
[System.Web.Mvc not functioning as expected after Windows Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396489/system-web-mvc-not-functioning-as-expected-after-windows-update)

I managed to fix all references in Web Projects with above link.
However in class libraries where I am referencing System.Web.MVC 4.0.0.1 I still receive the error:
The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context

I can see the correct DLL being referenced in the solution explorer - when looking at the properties it is set to 4.0.0.1.

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried remove reference and add it again?

Comment: Yes I did - no luck.

Comment: is nuget update works fine? check package.config for version. Also did you have this line `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"` in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has nothing to-do with the MS upgrade. It appears this code was added later and never compiled - even under 4.0.0.0 .. Apologies.